# Get a progress bar while a process ( function ) is working ----QT

Tags: c++, qt, progress

I am working on a project and I need to show the User a 'busy progress bar' or a 'GUI element' until a process is completed. this process is a function that need loft of time to finished ( Image Processing), I see QProcess , but it's doesn't help me because my processus s a fonction in my Class

Comment: is your question about running the function in a different thread too? or are you knowledgeable about that?

Comment: Why not use QProgressBar? If you spawn a process that does some work and is finished once it exits, you may use QProcess to determine when the task is finished, but you cannot do a QProgessBar with it, unless you use some kind of IPC to query the external process for the current progress.

Comment: @user3606329 , *QProcess doesn't help me because my processus s a fonction in my Class*

Comment: A function in a class is not a process. If the code is executed inside your application use QProgressBar in an own thread.

Comment: please provide more information about the function you are trying to call, and what have you tried so that we can help you.

Comment: I have buttonFunction() ; when i clicked on the button1 , the buttonFunction() will be called, and inside this function there is ImageProcessing() fonction witch will take 2mn to finished the processus, so i want to make progressBar that appear when the user click on the button1 and it will show them the processus's time.                                       i hope that you will understand Mike, user3606329

Comment: @bz_benzait , what is the return type of `ImageProcessing()`?

Comment: Mike ; the return type of ImageProcessing() is void